# Where to handle callback when using Forge Webhooks : server or client side?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-webhooks

I am trying to use Forge Webhooks API to monitor the translation progress of my model with Model Derivative API.
I use :

- C# Web ApiControllers on server side
- jQuery/JS on client side

I am not sure about where to handle callbacks from Webhooks API. I started writting the callback receiver in the C# ApiController (server side) :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/webhook/callback")]
    public HttpResponseMessage WebhookCallback(dynamic info)
    {
        string urn = info.resourceUrn;

        // do things

        // redirect to root
        HttpResponseMessage res = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved /* force redirect */);
        res.Headers.Location = new Uri("/", UriKind.Relative); // back to / (root, default)

        return res;
    }
```

But then I realized I can't execute JS client side functions from this Controller method, for instance to show the model in the viewer.

Do I need to write the callback receiver in the JS client side part? If so, how?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webhook need to call a stable URL, so on your server side, which then calls your client side (e.g. using [websocket](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-2.1) )

We have a .NET sample [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-webhook), sorry it doesn’t yet implement the websocket

Comment: Would you advise SignalR for websocket implementation ? I'm afraid my prod server will be on Windows Server 2008 R2, so it won't support websockets.

Comment: seems possible from what I read at https://www.asp.net/signalr, there is no limitation or restrictions from Forge on this, you can choose the best technology/library for it

Comment: In Supported platforms section, you can read "Note that for SignalR to use WebSockets, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2016, or Windows 8 is required".